# What is the relationship between maxExecutors, num-executors and initialExecutors when using Spark on YARN?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

At first, I read [this article](https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/admin-guide/engine-admin/spark-admin/autoscale-spark.html), which says `spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors` will have value equal to `num-executors` if `spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors` is not explicitly set. However, from the following part of this article, it says "`--num-executors` or `spark.executor.instances` acts as a minimum number of executors with a default value of 2", And it confuses me.

1. My first question is what is the usage of `--num-executors` in Spark 2.x or later versions? Does it act like a obsolete option which is useful before dynamicAllocation? When dynamicAllocation is introduced, `--num-executors` and `--max-executors` act more like some default values to `spark.dynamicAllocation.*`?
2. What is the difference between `--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors` and `--max-executor`? Does the later acts like an alias to the former?

Meanwhile, the article does not mention the relationship between `num-executors` and `spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors`. So I make a experiment in which I send the following arguments:

```
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=2  --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=20  --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=3 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=10  --num-executors 0  --driver-memory 1g  --executor-memory 1g  --executor-cores 2
```

And it turns out that initially 3 executor is allocated(correspond to `initialExecutors`) and then reduced to 2(correspond to `minExecutors`), and it seems that `--num-executors` is useless here. However, the article says "-num-executors or spark.executor.instances acts as a minimum number of executors", so there is a contradiction now.

3. My third question is what is the relationship between `num-executors` and `spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors`, is `spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors` prior to `num-executors`? From the [document](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation), I find when `num-executors` is set larger than `spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors`, it will override `spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors`.

Comment: Did you find answer to this question, looking out for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your first article is from Qubole's developer guide, it is not necessarily reflective of Apache Spark's default behavior.

To answer your questions:

1. `num-executors` is not necessarily made obsolete, if you have dynamic allocation set using a separate process or command, `num-executors` acts as a safeguard for proper allocation if dynamic allocation is ever turned off for whatever reason. For that reason, I usually have `num-executors` set equal to `spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors`.
2. I'm unaware of `max-executors`, but I would assume that it is an alias with the lesser of that and `spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors` being the set maximum if both are specified, going by spark's typical logic. Best to just use `spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors`.
3. `num-executors` behaves as `spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors` not as `spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors` when using dynamic allocation. I've observed that the greater of `num-executors` and `initialExecutors` is what is used if both are set.